# EXC_??? (11) (code=0, subcode=0x0) in dispatch_async block

Tags: ios, block, dispatch

I've got the following code which stops at `if (time != currentTime)` and launches the debugger.  I cannot find any info about it, and trying to log an exception isn't working.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self startIt];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self stopIt];
}

- (void)startIt {
    isRunning = YES;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        @try {
            NSTimeInterval time = currentTime;
            while (isRunning) {
                if (time != currentTime) {  // app stops here with EXC_??? (11)
                    time = currentTime;
                    // do other work
                }
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *e) {
            NSLog(@"Exception %@", e);
        }
    });
}

// Delegate method called when broadcasting time
- (void)updateCurrentTime:(NSInteger)time {
    @synchronized(self) {
        currentTime = time;
    }
    [anotherView doStuffWIthTime:time];
}

- (void)stopIt {
    isRunning = NO;
}
```

Viewing the stack trace isn't helping me much:

```
* thread #6: tid = 0x2503, 0x0021e6e3 Project`__46-[MyViewControlleriPad startRunQueue]_block_invoke() + 131 at MyViewControlleriPad.m:343, stop reason = EXC_??? (11) (code=0, subcode=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0021e6e3 Project`__46-[MyViewControlleriPad startRunQueue]_block_invoke() + 131 at MyViewControlleriPad.m:343
    frame #1: 0x03f1653f libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    frame #2: 0x03f28014 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
    frame #3: 0x03f192e8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 335
    frame #4: 0x03f19450 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
    frame #5: 0x96f33e72 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 441
```

EDIT: Updated to show `isRunning` being set.  I'm now realizing I'm not synchronizing access to it.  Will that fix this issue?  I was thinking it was with `currentTime`.

Comment: Where do you initialize isRunning ?

Comment: I updated the code to show it being set.  It's initialized in the main thread, so I need to synchronize that, too.

Comment: How are you calling startIt et updateCurrentTime ?